# Golang + MongoDB Official Driver vs Quarkus Reactive MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, go, kubernetes, quarkus

I am trying to implement a project on the cloud for as minimum resources as possible (cpu, ram usage) and be able to handle medium to large number of requests through the database.

For the database part, I have chosen mongodb but for the backend I am between golang or quarkus.

Golang has many advantages but the only thing that concerns me is the interaction with mongodb. Mongodb official driver for Golang doesn't support reactive interface and despite the fact that golang can be easily implemented to be async I am afraid that mongodb will be my bottleneck.

Quarkus looks very promising, it is supported by Red Hat and it has been built to address many issues for the cloud era. It has been built on top of async servers and supports reactive communication with mongodb.

What is your opinion of the above? What would you suggest?

Thanks,

Comment: By "reactive interface", do you mean [MongoDB change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)? If so, the official driver does support it, see [`mongo.ChangeStream`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#ChangeStream).

Comment: I am looking something similar to this: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/  - MongoDB Reactive Streams Driver
 but for golang

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing these tests. Reactive quarkus and golang. So far go is much better

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31312462)